# TortoiseSVN Diff With "specific file" does not go away

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, diff

Not sure how this happened but when I right-click on a modified file and go to the TortoiseSVN submenu I also see `Diff with "path/to/some/file"`. It's been like this for a long time, so I don't remember what steps put it there in the first place. And also it's always the same exact file. This doesn't affect the general usage of TortoiseSVN, it's just an annoyance because there's an extra context-menu option that I'm never going to use...

If anyone has a clue how to get rid of this (and also knows how it got there in the first place) I'd appreciate any help I can get.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If anyone has a clue how to get rid of this

You can check the Windows Registry and remove the value `DiffLater` under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseMerge`. That's kind of hacky and I expect that there is a better way to get rid of that option. However, I don't know how to do that another way. I recall similar question asked recently, so it could be a bug in TortoiseSVN. You may want to ask the question in the [TortoiseSVN users@ mailing list](https://tortoisesvn.net/community.html).

> (and also knows how it got there in the first place)

Some time ago you right-clicked an unversioned file and selected the **Diff later** command.

Comment: Do you mean remove the value (i.e. just delete the contents of the DiffLater key), or remove the entire DiffLater key?

Comment: Ok, I just deleted the contents (leaving the key itself there) and it worked great. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 6):

Difference between files [Tortoise SVN doc](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-diff.html):

> ...To remove the marked file, use the command TortoiseSVN → Diff later again, but hold down the Ctrl-modifier while clicking on it.

Comment: This was the simplest way for me to get rid of the Diff with "..." option. Just Ctrl + left click on Diff later option and the Diff with "..." is removed